# Return inside or outside the for?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm losing my mind here. I'm trying to do a post request using parameters that need to go in the body of the post..
This object only have one property step.
I do this by using a for, in each iteration I send an object as param.

The thing is that if i put the return inside the for,WORKS! but its finish after send me the first object and that doesn't work for me.
if i put the return outside the for throw me this error: Converting circular structure to json

help!!
thks!!

code over here:
app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const itemsController = require('../controller/itemsController')
const saveController = require('../controller/saveController')

const app = express()

.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}))
.use(bodyParser.json())


.get('/api/v1/items', itemsController.getItems)

.get('/api/v1/save', saveController.postItems)

.use(function(error, req, res, next){
    console.log('error', error)
})

module.exports = app
```

controller.js

```js
function postItems(req, res, next){
    eventService.getItems()
    .then(response => {
     const eventType = response.items.filter(type => type.type == 'LIVE')

        for(var i =  10; i < eventType.length; i++){ 
              const res = eventService.postItems(nameFilter[i])
              // return eventService.postItems(nameFilter[i])
        } 
        return res    
    })
   .then(response => {
        res.send(response)
    }) 
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error')
        next(error)
    }) 
}
```

service:

```js
async postItems(param) {

    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': await getToken.getToken()
        },
        url: 'url',
        data: param
      })
      return response.data

    } catch (error) {
      console.log( error)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're reusing the variable named `res` and that's leading to confusion, along with some help from block scoping. You're trying to return the `postItems` param `res`. The identically named variable inside of your loop is const, hence block scoped and doesn't exist outside of the loop, hence the confusion.

Comment: Thanks Nit.. so i have to change the name of res variable?

Comment: The problem isn't the reused name, the reused name is making you miss your actual error.

Answer (score -1):

No matter where you put it, it will only return a single value. You could try using `Promise.all` with a generator <s>(not tested yet!)</s>:

```js
function postItems(req, res, next){
    eventService.getItems()
    .then(response => Promise.all(function*(){
        const eventType = response.items.filter(type => type.type == 'LIVE')

        for(var i = 10; i < eventType.length; i++){
              const res = eventService.postItems(nameFilter[i]))
              yield res
        }
    }()))
    .then(responses => {
        Promise.all(responses.map(response => res.send(response)))
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error')
        next(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks Solomon.. i try your code and fails..says: ` Cannot read property 'req' of undefined`.. any suggestions?

Comment: @AgustinWaldbottvonBassenhei Where is it trying to read the property?

Comment: i think is trying on app file: `.get('/api/v1/save', saveController.postItems)
.use(function(error, req, res, next){
    console.log(' error', error)
})`

Comment: @AgustinWaldbottvonBassenhei I'm not sure. That also seems like a separate question. Try to create [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i edited just now

Comment: @AgustinWaldbottvonBassenhei I haven't used Express before, but according to the docs, the argument names for `use` are just conventions, so I'm not really sure what's causing the error. Could you post the whole error message, especially the stack trace, **as a separate question**? (Feel free to add cross-links, though, if you want.)

Comment: thank you for your help. i paste the complete error here. Hops it help: `error TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined
    at send (/home/my/Desktop/Work1/node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:110:18)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at eventService.getItems.then.then.responses (/home/my/Desktop/Work1/node/controller/saveController.js:21:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`

Comment: @AgustinWaldbottvonBassenhei Does specifying the parameters fix it? (`Promise.all(responses.map(response => res.send(response)))`) Does `responses` contain an array of responses, as it should? If not, you can let me know here, but otherwise, it's probably a separate issue, and you should [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: i create another issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56111666/error-node-typeerror-cannot-read-property-req-of-undefined-at-send