# Error node TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined at send

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm losing my mind here. I'm trying to do a post request using parameters that need to go in the body of the post.. This object only have one property step. I do this by using a for,yield and promise and i get this error..
responses is undefined.. why? thanks!

controller.js

```
function postItems(req, res, next){
    eventService.getItems()
    .then(response => Promise.all(function*(){
        const eventType = response.items.filter(type => type.type == 'LIVE')

        for(var i = 10; i < eventType.length; i++){
              const res = eventService.postItems(nameFilter[i])
              yield res
        }
    }()))
    .then(responses => {
        Promise.all(responses.map(response => res.send(response))) //fails here
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error')
        next(error)
    })
}
```

service

```
async postItems(param) {

    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': await getToken.getToken()
        },
        url: 'url',
        data: param
      })
      return response.data

    } catch (error) {
      console.log( error)
    }
  }
}
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const itemsController = require('../controller/itemsController')
const saveController = require('../controller/saveController')

const app = express()

.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}))
.use(bodyParser.json())


.get('/api/v1/items', itemsController.getItems)

.get('/api/v1/save', saveController.postItems)

.use(function(error, req, res, next){
    console.log('error', error)
})

module.exports = app
```

Comment: after `for` loop please return `res`.

Comment: What is the value of `responses`? I'm not sure why it would be `undefined`. Try adding `console.log(responses)` within `responses => { ... }`.

Comment: @VikashSingh `res` is only in scope inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @VikashSingh They are yielding it in a generator...?

Comment: @VikashSingh At least the value of the constant declared inside the loop.

Comment: It *probably* isn't the source of the problem, but note that the `res` constant declared inside the loop shadows (hides) the parameter, inside the loop. Changing it would make the code clearer.

Comment: My only point is that first `.then` promise should return some value. Here in above code there is not returned value thats why responses value is undefined.

Comment: @VikashSingh `Promise. all` resolves with an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all The generator returns an iterable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Answer (score 1):

A problem I see here is that you are calling `response.send` several times. Internally, it calls `response.end()`, which disallows further invocations of `response.send`. In your case, you should use `response.write`.

Reference: https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/node-js/express-js/response-send-end-write-difference/

Comment: i try whit `responses.map(res.write) and throw `Cannot read property 'finished' of undefined`

Comment: @AgustinWaldbottvonBassenhei, could post the entire error stack trace here? Maybe we can identify the problem by the files where it occurs